# C# SpinLock and Threading. StackOverflowException and Exited with code 259 (0x103)

Tags: c#, multithreading, stack-overflow, spinlock

I'm incredibly new to C#, but the goal of this project was to have a prime number generator use thread locking and use multiple processing cores. I thought I was getting the hang of C#, but I'm running into a few issues.

Running in Visual Studio gives a bunch of: Exited with code 259 (0x103) messages. 
I've read that this is a bug with Visual Studio and is actually not an issue?

The core of the issue is a StackOverflowException. I'm familiar with the concept of a stack overflow, but I'm having trouble identifying where it is occurring. I can guess it has something to do with filling my queues somewhere.

Program is laid out as follows:

Calculator.cs: Reads numbers from a generated file, puts them in a queue, starts threading on those queues

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace PrimeProject{
internal class Calculator {

    public void Run(NumberReader reader) {
        var results = new List<long>();
        var numbersToCheck = new Queue<long>();

        StartComputationThreads(results, numbersToCheck);

        var progressMonitor = new ProgressMonitor(results);

        new Thread(progressMonitor.Run) {IsBackground = true}.Start();

        var someList = new List<long>();
        foreach (var value in reader.ReadIntegers()) 
        {
            someList.Add(value);
            if (someList.Count == 1000)
            {
                numbersToCheck.EnqueueCollection(someList);
                someList.Clear();
            }
        }
        if (someList.Count > 0)
        {
            numbersToCheck.EnqueueCollection(someList);
            someList.Clear();
        }

        while (numbersToCheck.Count() > 0) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // wait for the computation to complete.
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} of the numbers were prime", progressMonitor.TotalCount);
    }

    private static void StartComputationThreads(List<long> results, Queue<long> numbersToCheck) 
    {
        var threads = CreateThreads(results, numbersToCheck);
        threads.ForEach(thread => thread.Start());
    }

    private static List<Thread> CreateThreads(List<long> results, Queue<long> numbersToCheck) 
    {

        var threadCount = Environment.ProcessorCount*2;

        Console.WriteLine("Using {0} compute threads and 1 I/O thread", threadCount);

        var threads =
            (from threadNumber in Sequence.Create(0, threadCount)
                let calculator = new IsNumberPrimeCalculator(results, numbersToCheck)
                let newThread =
                    new Thread(calculator.CheckIfNumbersArePrime) {
                        IsBackground = true,
                        Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
                    }
                select newThread).ToList();
        return threads;
    }
}
}
```

Semaphore.cs: Custom queue class, creates semaphores, SpinLock calls. Updated with bool lockTaken before try{}.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

internal sealed class Queue<T>
{
private readonly Semaphore semaphoreOne;
private readonly Semaphore semaphoreTwo;
private readonly SpinLock _spinLock;
private readonly Queue<T> listQueue;

public Queue()
{
    this.semaphoreOne = new Semaphore(0x3e8, 0x3e8);
    this.semaphoreTwo = new Semaphore(0, 0x3e8);
    this._spinLock = new SpinLock();
    this.listQueue = new Queue<T>();
}

public int Count()
{
    int count;
    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        this._spinLock.Enter(ref lockTaken);
        count = this.listQueue.Count();
    }
    finally
    {
        this._spinLock.Exit();
    }
    return count;
}

public void EnqueueCollection(IReadOnlyCollection<long> collection)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
    {
        this.semaphoreOne.WaitOne();
    }
    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        this._spinLock.Enter(ref lockTaken);
        foreach (long local in collection)
        {
            this.listQueue.Enqueue(local);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        this._spinLock.Exit(true);
    }
    this.semaphoreTwo.Release(collection.Count);
}

public void Enqueue(long num)
{
    this.semaphoreOne.WaitOne();
    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        this._spinLock.Enter(ref lockTaken);
        this.listQueue.Enqueue(num);
    }
    finally
    {
        this._spinLock.Exit();
    }
    this.semaphoreTwo.Release(1);
}

public long Dequeue()
{
    long local;
    this.semaphoreTwo.WaitOne();
    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        this._spinLock.Enter(ref lockTaken);
        local = this.listQueue.Dequeue();
    }
    finally
    {
        this._spinLock.Exit();
    }
    this.semaphoreOne.Release();
    return local;
}
}
```

SpinLock.cs: Removed due to changes in Semaphore.cs

other classes (for reference) include: isNumberPrime, progressMonitor, reader, and writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SpinLock` class seems to have its own instance, Not sure what your intention is, but that leads to infinite creation of `SpinLock` instance which exploits all the stack memory and thus leads to `StackoverflowException`.

I suggest you to give a different name for your class as `SpinLock` is already taken by BCL.

Comment: I had it named differently initially, but it caused problems in the Semaphore.cs whenever I call "this._spinLock.Enter()" it requires ref bool. Should I put the bool lockTaken and while loop and put it in my Semaphore class?

Comment: I just updated the code above. I think by putting bool lockTaken in the try{} sections, I actually don't need my SpinLock class anymore? Though I still get stack overflow errors.

Comment: @JoeLaMagReiter Yes, your spinlock class adds no value and hence can be removed. At which point you get stackoverflow? Do you completely deleted the `SpinLock` class?

Comment: Yes, the SpinLock class has been removed from the project. The updated Semaphore.cs code has been updated above in the post. And yes, still getting stackoverflow errors.

Comment: So, it seems when running the code, Visual Studio just popped up a box pointing to `this.semaphoreOne = new Semaphore(0x3e8, 0x3e8);` and saying stack overflow. I tried changing these to regular integers with no luck. Am I handling semaphores incorrectly?

Comment: Ah, I got it. Your `Queue<T>` class also create instance of itself in `this.listQueue = new Queue<T>();` You better rename your Queue class or write `private readonly System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T> listQueue;` and `this.listQueue = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>();`

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the help. I'm beating myself up over here for my sloppy code.